# ¿Cómo puedo enumerar con este metodo? PHP

Tags: php, java, mysql

tengo un servidor con un plugin de java (no es mío) en el cual guarda información y estadísticas del usuario, guardandolo como en un string, enumerando el texto y obteniendo las estadísticas de ese jugador. Me preguntaba si podría hacer lo mismo pero en PHP, un ejemplo de como se guarda la información en la base de datos es esta:

`2:220:0:2:1:0:0:8:31:10:0:1:0`

¿Puedo obtener como un array, todos los valores que estén separados de los dos puntos?, lo que intente hacer fué usar esto

`$resultado['stats'][0];`

Pero me dí cuenta que los valores pueden aumentar y no serviría esto, ¿Alguna manera de como podría obtener la información?

Comment: Tienes la función `explode` de PHP para separar cada elemento. Mira el enlace de la doc https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php. en tu caso el separador entiendo que es el carácter `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corta el string con el metodo `explode` de `php`

```
$string ="2:220:0:2:1:0:0:8:31:10:0:1:0";
$array = explode(":",$string);

//para ver cada registro
foreach($array as $k=> $value){
  var_dump($value);
}
```